# how to make a custom container in top of another one in flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gridview, containers, customization

guys I need help in my flutter app
I want to make a custom Container (that containe an image) in the top of anothr custom Container(that contain a column with two text and an icon)
all this is is a widget of a gird view
I code this but I did't get what I need

custom card :

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WordCustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const WordCustomCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      children: [
        Card(
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'text1',
                ),
                Text(
                  'text2',
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_circle_up_outlined,
                  size: 30,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Card(
            child: Image(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/alg.png'),
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
        )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The class where I'm using the custom card :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lahgat/components/word_custom_card.dart';

class HomeTap extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeTap({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeTap> createState() => _HomeTapState();
}

class _HomeTapState extends State<HomeTap> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffF7F8FA),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              /* Container(
                height: 50,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text('data'),
                    Text('data'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),*/
              Container(
                height: 150,
                width: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text('data'),
                    Text('data'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: GridView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  itemCount: 9,
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return const WordCustomCard();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Positioned` widget in your `Stack` widget around the `Card` that have your image.
The argument of the `Positioned` widget will allow you to overflow on the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your widget **WordCustomCard** like this:

```
class WordCustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const WordCustomCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      children: <Widget>[
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Text(
                      'text1',
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      'text2',
                    ),
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_circle_up_outlined,
                      size: 30,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const Positioned(
          top: -15,
          child: Card(
              child: Image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/alg.png'),
            width: 30,
            height: 30,
          )),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```